" character in b2c custom policy
I have a string collection in a custom policy.
I need to find if one of the strings in the string collection contains certain value.
The problem is that the value is /"id/" /"guid/". How do I introduce the " character in the custom policy so I can use claims transformations to check for the value?``

To introduce the " character in a string within an Azure AD B2C custom policy, you can escape it by using a backslash (). For example, if you want to check if a string in your collection contains the value /"id/" /"guid/", you would represent it as /"id/" / "guid/" in your claims transformation rules. This allows you to properly include the double quotes in your string comparisons.

Custom policies are just XML files, you should be able to use &quot; in the XML and B2C will interpret that as ".
